# Spawn Enemy GameObject only infornt of the Camera view while camera moves with the Player GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to spawn enemies on fixed z-axis and between random x-axis points. I am making the Ground a child of the Player so it moves with the Player. The Player can only move on the Horizontal axis. I want to make it look like the Enemies are always spawning in front of the Player. How can I do it so? Right now if I move Ground with Player, the Enemies spawn only at the designated points.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnManager : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private GameObject _enemy;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(SpawnRoutine());
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}

IEnumerator SpawnRoutine()
{
    while(true)
    {
        Vector3 PosToSpawn = new Vector3(Random.Range(-23.6f, 23.6f),1, 16.6f);
        Instantiate(_enemy, PosToSpawn, Quaternion.identity);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER**

Get a reference to the Ground object using the same approach as your reference to the enemy object.

```
[SerializeField]
private GameObject _ground;
```

Replace:

```
Vector3 PosToSpawn = new Vector3(Random.Range(-23.6f, 23.6f),1, 16.6f);
```

With:

```
Vector3 PosToSpawn = new Vector3(Random.Range(_ground.transform.position.x - 23.6f, _ground.transform.position.x + 23.6f), 1, 16.6f);
```

This will work, provided that you are updating the position of the ground object relative to the player object as you say you are.

**OLD ANSWER (changed after the example script was changed):**

If I understand your question/problem correctly, your enemies are spawning in the same places every time your run the game even though you're using Random.Range to set their x value.

If that is your actual problem, then it's caused because your game always uses the same seed for its random number generation.

You can generate a new random seed every time you start the game by using an arbitrary value such as the System.DateTime.Now.Ticks.  Put the following code into your Start method (not your Update method):

```
int seed = (int) System.DateTime.Now.Ticks;
Random.InitState(seed);
```

What the above code does is, get the current system time ticks (which will change every time you run the game) and then initializes the random number generator using that value as the seed.  This should result in different spawn locations each time you run the game.

For more info look at:

- https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/Random-seed.html
- https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.InitState.html

Comment: Hey, Sorry but no that's not what I am looking for. I am trying to spawn the enemies within my camera angle no matter where I move and the above script is only the enemy script. I have different scripts for Spawning and Player movement.

Comment: @kunalsingh No worries. I was confused by the fact that you had posted the enemy script rather than a spawn script so I assumed that your problem was related to the line where you update the enemy position.  To answer your question, we would need to see how you're currently determining where your enemies are spawned.  Without that information, all I can say is that you'll have to make use of the Camera frustrum planes: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes.html

Comment: I changed the Enemy script to the SpawnManager Script above. Please take a look